# Popen stops working after a few interactions

Tags: python, pipe

I'm trying to interact with an external program using `subprocess.Popen class`. The external program takes an input and returns an output. I'm following the examples in [here](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/) but it seems that the `Popen` stops working after a few interactions. Here is an example:

This is the code for `test.sh`

```
# test.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
echo Hello, who am I talking to?
read varname
echo It\'s nice to meet you $varname
done
```

And run this code in python 3

```
import subprocess
import io
print('One line at a time:')
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    'test.sh',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
stdin = io.TextIOWrapper(
    proc.stdin,
    encoding='utf-8',
    line_buffering=True,  # send data on newline
)
stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
    proc.stdout,
    encoding='utf-8',
)
for i in range(5):
    line = '{}\n'.format(i)
    stdin.write(line)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = stdout.readline()
    print(output.rstrip())
remainder = proc.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
print(remainder)
```

And this is the output I get:

```
One line at a time:
Hello, who am I talking to?
It's nice to meet you 0
Hello, who am I talking to?
It's nice to meet you 1
Hello, who am I talking to?
```

The program hangs after this.

So why does Popen stop working in this example?

Comment: The loop needs to read the greeting from `stdout`, then write the name to `stdin`, and then read the response from `stdout`. Then in test.sh you should use a finite `for` loop instead of an infinite loop, else `communicate()` will never return. It will just keep reading "Hello, who am I talking to?" and "It's nice to meet you" endlessly.

Comment: @eryksun I still don't understand, why does it stop at `i=2`? If there is a problem with the `communicate()` I will expect it to stop at `i=5`.

Comment: It needs to read two lines for every line it writes, not one line.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! That solves the problem!